# Grub problems with 32bit EFI on Winpad Tablet

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I've been struggling for days now to get this to work...

I have a Windpad 10 on which I want to run Ubuntu. The tablet only has a 32bit UEFI so I needed the "bootia32.efi" workaround to get it to boot from USB in the first place. Sometimes I also need "nomodeset" otherwise the screen stays black. I always got a grub installation error though and the entire installation process terminates. Only with 17.10 AND(!) enabled updates during installation it installed somehow.

But booting is not working correctly.

When a cold boot is performed It'll show the manfacturer logo and then a puple screen for ca 1 second followed by a black screen of which I can not recover. Shift is working (indicated by keyboard LED) and when I reboot via "alt + SysRq + r , e , i , s , u , b" I see for a very short time that it actually booted to dekstop just fine, it just didn't show anything.

When I reinstall Grub or use Boot Repair my EFI32/Grub setup is completly destroyed and I get a blue message box on startup saying something like "failed to boot ubuntu". Only wiping the HDD and a fresh install recovers from that.

I noticed that when I hit ESC during the one second the purple screen is shown Grub suddenly appears and I can (sometimes) actually boot into Ubuntu with working display output. Other times it's stuck at the same black screen.

I tried a lot already... I'm suspecting some kind of graphics driver loading race condition within Grub but everything I tried so far destroyed EFI32/Grub.

Some more Info:

Ubuntu 17.10 x64 4.13.0-16-generic

efibootmgr -v

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0002,0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,7b03d4ea-4880-46f7-9c6b-0fcdd21026dc,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubia32.efi)
Boot0001* Windows Recovery  FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(c57ad6b7-0515-40a8-9d21-551652854e37)RCs...
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,7b03d4ea-4880-46f7-9c6b-0fcdd21026dc,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grub.efi)RC
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
```

blkid

```
/dev/mmcblk1: PTUUID="8d7cc013-1c2c-4d5f-b954-7c2ed86daf59" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/mmcblk1p1: UUID="387E-CDF3" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="7b03d4ea-4880-46f7-9c6b-0fcdd21026dc"
/dev/mmcblk1p2: UUID="ad5aa97b-364e-4896-84fa-396ba6e24a3a" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="ce98b3d3-fd0e-47bb-be25-26dca1989bb2"
```

One more observation: When I installed Ubuntu and managed to boot into it the first time I rotated the Display to Landscape. It did work for some boot cycles (maybe until I ran an apt-get upgrade) but then it reverted to portrait and it does so immediately every time I try to set it to landscape again.

best regards 
Alex

Comment: Have you tried Lubuntu? Often these lightweight systems work better with a lightweight version of Ubuntu. Lightweight flavors
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu mate, Budgie
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors

Comment: Ok, I tried Lubuntu now. Basically the same behavior. Black Screen but when I force I restart I see for short time that it actually booted.

Comment: While nomodeset is normally for AMD or nVidia, have you tried that? Or recovery mode boot? It almost seems like screen brightness is turned down or off. Is that a separate setting. Not familiar with your system.

Comment: yeah i tried nomodeset. in the begininng I thought it helps but now if often goes to black screen even with nomodeset. I was thinking about the brightness thing as well, but the brightness controlls on the keyboard via fn have no effect. It's a Winpad 10 with an Intel Atom Z3735F

Comment: If you remove quiet splash and use nomodeset do you see the boot process?